# How to initialize, import message from protobuf as array in Golang

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf file as follows:

```
message Lesson {
  int64 UserId = 1;
  int32 CourseId = 2;
  int32 LessonId = 3;
  LessonStatus Status = 4;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp DateSubmitted = 5;
  
  message Question {
    string QuestionId = 1;
    string StudentAnswer = 2;
    QuestionStatus Status = 3;
    string SupComment = 4;

  }

  repeated Question Questions = 6;

}
```

}

The protobuf file is imported as `api`.

Creating a single object of `Lesson_Question` is simple, with `&api.Lesson_Question{}`, but I am trying to create a slice of Questions. I have been Googling for a while and don't find any documentation on this.

I have tried all sorts of combinations, such as:

- `questions := []*api.Lesson_Question`
- `questions := []&api.Lesson_Question`
- `questions := &[]api.Lesson_Question`
- `questions := *[]api.Lesson_Question`
- `questions := []api.Lesson_Question`

but all give an error.

Any assistance or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using go-grpc, the `Questions` member will be generated as `[]*api.Lesson_Question`. To declare a literal:

```
empty_questions:=[]*api.Lesson_Question{}
questions:=[]*api.Lesson_Question{&api.Lesson_Question{QuestionId:"q1"},
  &api.Lesson_Question{QuestionId:"q2"}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. :)